# How to make Overlay to show above canvas.drawLine in Android map API

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, drawable

I have used the `draw()` method of my SitesOverlay class that is extending the `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` to draw some lines. Now, I am also putting in multiple images to the map as overlay by adding this one image to the `List<OverlayItem>` at many different points.
What happens now is that wherever the line (drawn using the `draw()` method) and the image icon overlap, the line is drawn over the overlayed image.
How do I make the overlay image come on top of the line?

Edit: I am using populate() to put all my overlays on the map, as soon as i add them to the list. IS there any way I can call populate *after* I have used my draw() method? I tried putting populate into the draw() method but the application stopped working...any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it figures that if you are using the draw method, then whatever you draw using it, will be drawn over your overlays. This is because `draw()` is called every time you drag/zoom or do anything with the map and overlays are populated only at the beginning...so drawn lines using `draw()` will always come over the overlays..

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing my source

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {

                OverlayItem item = getItem(i);
                String driverName = item.getSnippet();

                Data.activlyShownDrivers.add(driverName);

                Point screenPts = new Point();
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), screenPts);

                Bitmap bmp = null;
                Context ctx = ShowAll.getContext();
                long angle = (long) Double.parseDouble(item.getTitle());

                // ---add the marker---

                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.img1);


                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y, null);
                canvas.drawText(driverName, screenPts.x, screenPts.y, paint);

            }
            // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Log.e(Data.LOG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: ok..in ur code you are adding the image in the draw method. But I am adding the images into the overlayItem list. This addition into the list takes place in the constructor of the class that has draw() method as one of its methods....could you plz provide a solution related to that? As there are many overlay images to be added, it is best to add them into the overlay Items list in its constructor..doesnt mess things up. It would be great if i wouldnt have to move all my images from the constructor into my draw method..

Comment: can u plz reply and explain ur code. Did u populate() ur overlays before using draw()? If u already have ur overlays in place then what is img1? plz need help.